# Получение информации из Input на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как лучше всего сделать получение информации из переменной, которую мы получаем из формы на сайте? Допустим мы спрашиваем у пользователя:

> "Как вас зовут и сколько вам лет?"

и пользователь пишет в `input`

> "меня зовут *name и мне *age лет".

Как мы можем получить значение `*name` и `*age` на `JS`? Буду Благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

Это одни из вариантов. Таких вариантов могут быть тысячи. Легче разделить поля на двое )

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var name = $('input').val().replace(/.*(?:[Зз](?:о|а|О|А)[Вв][Уу][Тт]\ ([А-Яа-я]+)|[Ии][Мм][Яя]\ ([А-Яа-я]+)|[Ии][Мм][Яя]\ [Мм][Оо](?:ёе)\ ([А-Яа-я]+)|[Зз][Вв][Аа][Тт][Ьь]\ ([А-Яа-я]+)|[Зз][Вв][Аа][Тт][Ьь]\ [Мм][Ее][Нн][Яя]\ ([А-Яа-я]+)|([А-Яа-я]+)\ [Зз](?:о|а|О|А)[Вв][Уу][Тт]).*/, '$1');
    var old = $('input').val().replace(/.*(?:[Мм][Нн][Ее]\ (\d+)\ [Лл][Ее][Тт]|[Лл][Ее][Тт]\ [Мм][Нн][Ее]\ (\d+)|[Жж][Ии][Вв][Уу]\ (\d+)\ [Гг][Оо][Дд]).*/, '$1');
    console.log('Имя: '+name+'; Возраст: '+old);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Как тебя зовут и сколько тебе лет?</p>
<input type="text" value="Меня зовут Юрий, мне 17 лет">
<button>Ответить</button>
```

Comment: Это настолько нестабильный способ, что я его в кошмарах видел.

Comment: Интересный способ, есть способ по проще? Что бы не прописывать какое именно это слово по счету?

Comment: @arthru, увы. Пользователь может написать любое значение. Проще разделить поля на 2 части (имя и возраст). Ну или нужно учитывать все варианты написания, а их больше миллиона )

Comment: @arthru, сейчас изменю вопрос записав в нём пару вариантов

Comment: мне нужно что бы слюбыми словами работало просто брало вместо слово со зездочкой зхначение

Comment: @arthru, это почти не возможно. Или сделать, что бы пользователь как то обозначал особо, где имя и где возраст. А одной строкой очень сложно сделать

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение вида

```
answerText.match(/^Меня зовут ([^, ]+), мне (\d+) лет$/);
```

где answerText это текст как ответил пользователь. Скобки нужны для обозначения "переменных" куда будет помещен результат. Считаем что после слова "зовут " пользователь поместил свое имя, и после имени идет пробел или запятая, это выражение "([^, ]+)", знак ^ означает "пока не", [] - альтернативный выбор, + означает одно и более повторений, дословно "пока не встретился пробел или запятая, читаем значение в переменную"
  (\d+) означает одна или более цифр, \d - обозначает цифру
Результатом answerText.match(...) будет массив, где индекс элемента соответствует номеру открывающейся скобки в выражении, все найденное выражение имеет индекс 0. Если совпадение не найдено то функция "match" вернет null.

Модификатор i в "/.../i" означает что поиск производим без учета регистра.

```js
function submitAnswer() {
  var answerText = document.getElementById("answer").value;
  var parsedAnswer = answerText.match(/^Меня зовут ([^, ]+), мне (\d+) лет.?$/i);
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  if (parsedAnswer && parsedAnswer.length === 3) {
    result.value = 'Вас зовут ' + parsedAnswer[1] + "\n" +
                  'Вам ' + parsedAnswer[2] + ' лет'; 
  } else {
    result.value = 'Ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста ответьте строкой вида "Меня зовут ВашеИмя, мне Число лет"';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type="text" size="30" value="Меня зовут Юрий, мне 17 лет" id="answer">
   <button onclick="submitAnswer()">Ответить</button>
</div>
<div>
   <label for="result">Ответ:</label>
   <textarea id="result" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#inpt").keyup(function(){
 var myString = document.getElementById("inpt").value;
 var myRegexp = /меня зовут (.*) и мне (.*) лет/g
 var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);

  document.getElementById("nm").innerHTML = match[1];
  document.getElementById("ag").innerHTML = match[2];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="inpt" style="width:500px">
<br>
name:<span id="nm"></span>
<br>
age:<span id="ag"></span>
</form>
```