# Получить значение input, а именно числовое значение, записанное в него с помощью класса

Tags: javascript

Как получить числовое значение, записанное в input, с помощью его класса?
Или значение можно получить только используя id?

Comment: Элемент по классу: document.querySelector('.my-class'). Значение соответственно document.querySelector('.my-class').value

Comment: для начала советую попробовать поискать в любой из популярных поисковых систем, и только потом задавать вопрос.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение информации из Input на JS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608180/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-input-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

```
document.querySelector('.className').value
document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].value // без точки и с индексом, так как возвращается список элементов.
```